# How to enforce https connection for all sub locations? JAX-RS JBoss

Tags: ssl, jboss, jax-rs, enforcement, security-constraint

The following section should enforce all clients to use a https connection.

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>securedapp</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee> 
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

What actually happens is that only the index.html page is secured by ssl. So a request like: `http://localhost/JAX-RS_Service/` is redirected to `https://localhost/JAX-RS_Service/` and the index.html page is displayed. The same is for `http://localhost/JAX-RS_Service/index.html`
But if I try to request `http://localhost/JAX-RS_Service/services/customers/1` , there is no redirection to https, thus everything is sent in plaintext over the wire.

The same is for enforcing authentication

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Authenticated customers only</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/customers/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>CUST</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

An url-pattern like`<url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>` won't do the job.

Why isn't the `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` working for subloacations. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I have no idea why, but the following configuration solved my problem.

```
    <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>SSL Secured WebService</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee> 
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Authenticated customers only</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/customers/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>CUST</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee> 
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

The `<user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee> 
    </user-data-constraint>` needs to be added in each `<security-constraint>` otherwise it won't work for JBoss. The interesting thing is that for Tomcat you have to define the `<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>` just once a time for the `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` and everything is secured properly. In my opinion this is much more reasonable!